# HTACCESS : Redirect (301) thousands of Url's containing directories to simple url's

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to convert with HTACCESS method tons of URL's allready produced (and **already indexed**...) by Wordpress for articles containing folders/subfolders **to simples URL's without any folder/subfolder name**.

Example:
FROM https://www.website.com/Animals/Cats/mycat.html TO https://www.website.com/mycat.html
FROM https://www.website.com/Animals/Dogs/mydog.html TO https://www.website.com/mydog.html
FROM https://www.website.com/Countries/France/bordeaux.html TO https://www.website.com/bordeaux.html
etc...

I already changed permalinks options in Wordpress config. So, now URL's produced are in the good format (Ex: https://www.website.com/bordeaux.html) without any folder name.

My problem is to redirect **all OLD Url's to this new format** to prevent 404 and preserve the rank.

If tryed to add in my .htacess this line :
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]` 
I egally tryed `RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$` method and it's the same. I'm going crazy with this.
What am i doing wrong and could you help me?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* never starts with a slash. But you can use this to only match the last path-segment when there are more "folders". And the target URL also needs to end in `.html` (as per your examples).

So, this can be written in a single directive:

```
RewriteRule /([^/]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This handles any level of nested "folders". But does not match `/foo.html` (the target URL) in the document root (due to the slash prefix on the regex), so no redirect-loop.

(No need for any preceding *conditions*.)

Here the `$1` backrefence includes the `.html` suffix.

Comment: Great. Exactly what i did'nt undertood during hours... Thank you for your eplainations. I think it will be really usefull for other people.

Answer (score 2):

Just match the last part of the url and pass it to the redirect:

```
RewriteRule /([^/]+)\.html$ /$1.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

It will match any number of directories like:

- https://www.website.com/dir1/page1.html
- https://www.website.com/dir1/dir2/page2.html
- https://www.website.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/page3.html
- https://www.website.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir3/page4.html

Comment: You just make my day ! Great ! Thank you.